# Android Studio - Broke my AVD path, Broke my Emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, ubuntu

I broke my emulator. Please take a look at my setup:

.bash_profile -

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/home/ninad/Android/Sdk
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=$ANDROID_HOME
```

When I start the emulator -

```
~/Android/Sdk/tools$ emulator -avd nexus5
PANIC: Broken AVD system path. Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT value 
[/home/ninad/Android/Sdk]!
```

My AVD is located at -

```
~/.android/avd$ ls
nexus5.avd  nexus5.ini
```

PLEASE HELP! :)

This all happened when I tried to figure out how to launch the emulator from Eclipse (Ubuntu Computer). When I set the Android SDK path to /home/ninad/Android/Sdk, in Eclipse I get the error -

```
Failed to get the required ADT version number from the SDK
DDMS files not found: /home/ninad/Android/Sdk/tools/traceview
```

Any ideas on this would help too :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should remove system images and remove your emulator and then reinstall it again . 
Once I faced some thing the same I remove all things that was related to and then reinstall those again.